# How to show the login form from other components?

Tags: angular

I have common header components and footer components. header component have login form script in model popup. I want show the login model popup when user click on  add review button in these component like `HomepageComponent`, `CountryDetailComponent`, `ExploreListComponent` & `DetailedPageComponent`. My code here. How to show only one login model popup for all?.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home',  component: HomepageComponent,},
      { path: ':city', component: CountryDetailComponent },  
      { path: ':city/:subscategory', component: ExploreListComponent }, 
      { path: ':city/:subscategory/:singleitem', component: DetailedPageComponent },
    ];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
         <app-header></app-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      `, 
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

**header.component.ts**

```
    import { Component,Renderer } from '@angular/core';
    import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'app-header',
      template: `header.component.html`,
    })

    export class HeaderComponent { 
     constructor(title: Title) {  }
    }
```

**header.component.html**

```
 <div>
     /* header menu here */ 
 </div>


 <div>
    /*login form here */ 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of handle event's b/w sibling components

I think you need this :

You can use EventEmitter,

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/XJwjQ6L7s95mmwHqbu9H?p=preview
```

Note :

You can use

```
<router-outlet (eventFromComponent)='handleClickEvent($event)'></router-outlet>
```

router-outlet is in your `app-component`, so you need to write the `handleClickEvent` function there. Then all you need to do is pass the value to the header component. On change event header will show the login form.

Comment: Will you please create one plunker for me with your existing code, I will change that as per this. @vel

Comment: or can we create separate component for login?

Comment: @vel , you can use it any way, but it depends on the project structure, login in different component is a good way to go

Comment: I want to pass some values to login. How to do that?

Comment: <login [somedata]='json of data' /> you can access somedata via @input inside login component

Comment: could please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683250/how-to-communicate-child-component-to-parent-sibling-components?