# how to communicate child component to parent sibling components?

Tags: angular

I want to show the popup from `bucket-modal.component.ts` when the user mouseover/mouseleave on the `list.component.ts`.
How to communicate between `list.component.ts` to `bucket-modal.component.ts`? My code is here.

**list.component.ts**

```
@Component({    
    selector: 'list',
    templateUrl: 'list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['list.component.css'],
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() state: boolean;
    @Output() toggle = new EventEmitter();
    onHover() {
    this.state = true;
    this.toggle.emit(this.state);
    console.log("state is ----------" + this.state);
    }
    onHoverOut() {
    this.state = false;
    this.toggle.emit(this.state);
    console.log("state is------ " + this.state);
    }
}
```

**list.component.html**

```
<a (mouseover)="onHover()" (mouseleave)="onHoverOut()">random Link list</a>
```

**listdetails.component.ts**

```
@Component({

    selector: 'app-list-detail',
    templateUrl: 'app-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app-list.component.css'],
})


export class ListDetailComponent implements OnInit {


}
```

**listdetails.component.html**

```
<list [elementslist]="listdetails" listingtype="3"></list>
<list [elementslist]="listdetails" listingtype="3"></list>
<list [elementslist]="listdetails" listingtype="3"></list>
<bucket-modal [(showMeaddBucket)]="show2ClickedBucket" [state]="PopUpshow" (toggle)="PopUpshow=$event"></bucket-modal>
```

**bucket-modal.component.ts**

```
@Component({    
    selector: 'bucket-modal',
    templateUrl: 'bucket-modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['bucket-modal.component.css'],
})



export class BucketModalComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() state: boolean;
      @Output() toggle = new EventEmitter();
    onHover() {
        this.state = true;
        this.toggle.emit(this.state);
        console.log("state is " + this.state);
    }
    onHoverOut() {
        this.state = false;
        this.toggle.emit(this.state);
        console.log("state is " + this.state);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a public method in `BucketModalComponent` which will show the popup dialog. Something like

```
export class BucketModalComponent implements OnInit {
  showDialog(): void {
    // Open the popup dialog
  }
}
```

Then you can call it in `listdetails.component.html`:

```
<list ... (toggle)="modal.showDialog()"></list>
<bucket-modal #modal ... ></bucket-modal>
```

Comment: I want to pass id to bucket model component. How to do that?

Comment: You can implement the `showDialog()` method to accept a parameter - the ID.

Comment: showDialog dialog not called. `showDialog(): void {
        console.log("test ");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider I have components like this,

```
// Components
-parent 1
    - child 11
-parent 2
    - child 21
-parent 3
    - chils 31

// NgModule
- NgModule
    -> that has all these components
    -> Provider : CommonService
```

Now I want to pass the data from child 11 to all the parent(1,2,3)

In that case, you need service, and that service needs to be at module level e.g CommonService
Now All you need to do is to inject that service in those components in which you want to access 
those data.

You can also create eventEmitter in CommonService and FireItFrom child11
and subscribe to that eventEmitter in your all parent components.

Comment: Could you please create a plunkr with minimal code?

Comment: @vel, sorry man it will take time, you have to explore by your self, I have explained the key thing that is needed.